# Reinstall broken recovery partition on High Sierra

Tags: partition, high-sierra, recovery, repair

macOS High Sierra (10.13) is the main OS on my Mac and it boots without issue. However, the recovery partition is corrupted and I cannot boot to it without seeing an error. How do I reinstall the recovery partition without having to disrupt my working main OS?

The machine I'm using was upgraded from Mavericks.

Meta Note: While there are similar questions for previous MacOS versions, I think unique issues relating to the new APFS in High Sierra justify a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything related to partitions on your main Mac, it’s best to perform a Time Machine backup.

After doing that, run the latest macOS High Sierra installer from the App Store. This should update macOS and restore the Recovery partition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I appreciate that the option of blasting away all data is already there in the High Sierra installer and I'm already all backed up. However, I'm specifically looking to avoid that approach because my machine could be down for one or more days.

Comment: To my knowledge, running the High Sierra installer should not erase any data, and it should take about an hour, depending on what Mac you are using.

Comment: what is the error you see ?

Comment: Well, I did a reinstall of High Sierra and Recovery partition still did not appear. Supposedly because of Boot camp partition, but is it really necessary to remove?